# xslt advanced date datetime conversion

Tags: xml, date, xslt, datetime

I'm newbie in xslt and I'm not able to figure out a solution for my problem...

I've to create an xslt that permits to make a conversion from a DateTime to a DateString and viceversa.

From:

```
<dtStatus>2011-02-01T21:23:04Z</dtStatus>
```

To:

```
<dtStatus>110201 21:23:04</dtStatus>
```

How to create the xsl code to make this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the string functions to extract specific pieces of string and combine them back together again:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath/Functions

For example, something like this should extract the date in your desired format:

```
concat(substring(dtStatus, 3, 2), substring(dtStatus, 6, 2), substring(dtStatus, 8, 2))
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but with some difficulties. Can you help me with an example? (or a link to an example). Thanks